# moderncv and page numbers not displaying if text too long

Tags: page-numbering, moderncv

I am using the `moderncv` package with the `classic` style.  I find that the page numbers do not appear if the text on the last page goes all the way to the bottom and is just on the verge of requiring another page.

This is the best minimal example I could develop, which I created by modifying the template that comes with the moderncv package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
%\cvlistitem{UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT AND THE NUMBERS WILL DISAPPEAR.}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

Note the line about two-thirds of the way through:

```
%\cvlistitem{UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT AND THE NUMBERS WILL DISAPPEAR.}
```

I find that if I uncomment this line, then the page numbers disappear.  With it commented out, the page numbers appear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Use `\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}` to get them back. Or even `scale=0.76` works for me.

Comment: I have reported the bug to the author of the package.  The problem can also be solved without adjusting the overall geometry by adding the line `\enlargethispage{6pt}` at the bottom.

Comment: I think the problem is not so much the `\cvlistitem` line mentioned but the `cvcolumns` environment at the end; as it is, one gets an overfull box warning and my guess is that this environment hides the page numbering.

Comment: I do not believe this to be the case as my actual tex document (not the minimal example provided above) does not have any `cvcolumns` environments whatsoever and still yields the problem.  Furthermore, if you adjust the order of the sections in the minimal example above so that the `cvcolumns` environment does not appear at the end, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem and I can't solve it in the suggested ways. For me, the following hack solved it:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}

\rfoot{\textit{\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  In particular, it is best to post complete working examples rather than code snippets.

Comment: To make it look like exactly how it should be, you can also give gray text color. Use second line like this: 
`\rfoot{\textcolor{gray}{\textit{\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}}}`